# Django admin cannot order function column

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the code below, I have change the description to html safe. The problem is the ordering is not working anymore, I cannot change the ordering to 'safe_description'.

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('safe_description',)
    search_fields = ('description',)
    ordering = ('description',)

    def safe_description(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(obj.description)
    safe_description.short_description = 'Description'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't magically know that `safe_description` is mapped to your `description` column.

Specify the db column with the `admin_order_field` attribute

```
safe_description.admin_order_field = 'description'
```

Comment: Documented in the last bullet point under [`list_display`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).